# Eclipse java file is now one long blank line?

Tags: java, eclipse

I recently opened a java file in an project that I had used last week. It is now one long blank line with an error. The line is 22606 characters long which is probably the length of my file. Is it gone for good?

SOLVED:

Right clicked on file name and went Team->History to get backup

Comment: What OS are you using? What happens if you look at the file in other text editors? What might have changed the content of the file? (Is it under source control?)

Comment: Have you tried to use the "Compare to... / History Version" (not sure about exact wording) capability of Eclipse in case you do not use any VCS?

Comment: What happens if you Ctrl-Shift-F to format it?

Comment: @chiastic-security "What happens if you Ctrl-Shift-F to format it?" - He said it was blank.  Why would you reformat a file that contains nothing but a blank line?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown to check if it really is blank!

Comment: I see.  I gave him credit for knowing it was blank.  Maybe he was wrong.

Comment: I had opened it up with other file editors and pasted it to word as well. Still a blank line! I am using windows and my laptop shut off suddenly which might have corrupted it?

Comment: The error is an Expected duration Toast.LENGTH_SHORT or Toast.LENGTH_LONG which is strange because that means that the file is still there somewhere

Comment: You might need to restore the file from one of the backups that you take meticulously carefully every night :)

Comment: You say you use eclipse so can you not just go: Right-click on file -> Team -> Show Local History?

Comment: @DanielStanley I didn't know this was a thing! Thank you it worked.

Comment: @user3078867 No worries, you mind accepting it as an answer then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you use eclipse so can you not just go: 
`Right-click on file -> Team -> Show Local History`?